# How to get the value of a html input and preform a google search?

Tags: javascript, html, search, input

I have a form with an input control, and a submit button. I would like the user to be able to enter their zip code, and then perform a Google search with what they entered into the input field.

I tried searching online, but couldn't find what I was looking for. I already know the query string format for a Google search, just a little rusty on my HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var box=document.getElementById('the_search_box');
window.location='http://www.google.com/search?q='+escape(box.value);
```

Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/G8euv/).

You should consider creating a [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/) though.

Comment: I tried this, but I get a JavaScript error. document.getElementByID(...) is null or not an object. 

Any idea why?

Comment: Ohh, should've mentioned you have to do this test AFTER the DOM loads so getElementById() finds your element. Popular solutions include using `window.init`.

Answer (score 5):

Simple html:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">

<input type="text" name="q">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will this allow me to pass the value from the input field, and add on to it?

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand your question - but as with any form, you can manipulate everything through the DOM if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the script called LMGTFY (Let Me Google That For You) -- pretty cool implementation.